# pprof does not reveal what is holding the lock

Tags: go

While I find that Go's pprof is very helpful to report lock issues through observing the "semaquire" waits, it appears to me it is not helping to report "who/what" is holding the lock in question.

For example, the following pprof output reveals various semaquire waits on lock sync.(*Mutex).Lock(0xbf038c) , but nothing indicates who is holding that lock and what it's stack trace was.

Pasted pprof output:
https://justpaste.it/10we7

Are there other means to obtain more precide details from pprof on this ? I am accessing this from the http debug such as

"http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=2"

Comment: yes, a "blocking profile": https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/, https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/profile, https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs,

Comment: interesting... I am using it as /debug/pprof/block?debug=2 but does not seem to show the locks that associate to the semaquire lock references. I can't seem to find a useful document that explains how to read that output

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you're looking for. You won't really be able to get that information from a profile, because pprof is only a sampling profiler. You may be able to find the answer with the execution tracer (`runtime/trace`, or `-trace` flag in `go test`). Though in this situation, I've resorted to just annotating each Lock/Unlock operation.